# Accessing a .txt file through Java

Tags: java

I'm not the greatest Java coder, but I took on an assignment that requires me to access a .txt file in Java. This is the Stanford Nifty for Spelling Bee [(you can find it here)](http://nifty.stanford.edu/2022/eroberts-spelling-bee-wordle/SpellingBee/java/SpellingBeeAssignment.pdf)

Here's a sample of the text within the file. Note each word is on a new line.

```
a
aa
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
aardvark
aardvarks
aardwolf
aardwolves
aargh
aas
aasvogel
aasvogels
aba
abaca
abacas
abaci
aback
abacus
abacuses
abaft
```

Here's the solveAction() method that's supposed to run when a button is pressed.

```
private void solveAction() throws IOException {
        String puzzle = sbg.getBeehiveLetters();

//getBeehiveLetters() just checks what the letters you inputted to the puzzle are, given a //puzzleAction() method that takes a string and inputs the string into the puzzle

        // Read words from the file
        ArrayList<String> wordList = readWordsFromFile(ENGLISH_DICTIONARY);
 //English_Dictionary is a final string defined as the text file (EnglishWords.txt)

        // Find all valid words using the checkValidWord function
        ArrayList<String> validWords = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String word : wordList) {
            if (checkValidWord(word, puzzle)) {
                validWords.add(word);
            }
        }

        if (validWords.isEmpty()) {
            sbg.showMessage("No valid words found", Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            sbg.showMessage("Found words:", Color.BLACK);
            for (String word : validWords) {
                sbg.addWord(word, Color.BLUE);
            }
//showMessage and addWord are already implemented in a separate class
        }
    }

    // Check if a word is valid based on the puzzle
    private boolean checkValidWord(String word, String puzzle) {
        // Check word length
        if (word.length() < 4) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check for only puzzle letters
        for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
            if (!puzzle.contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Check for center letter at the start
        if (word.charAt(0) != puzzle.charAt(0)) {
            return false;
        }

        // All checks passed, word is valid
        return true;
    }
```

This code runs fine, but then I run the readWordsFromFile method, and I am met with a situation where no words are checked when its run.

```
public ArrayList<String> readWordsFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Clean and filter the line (optional)
                line = line.trim().toLowerCase(); // Remove whitespace and convert to lowercase
e
                // Add the word only if it has valid characters and length
                if (isValidWord(line)) {
                    words.add(line);
                }
            }
        }

        return words;
    }

    // Check if a word is valid based on your criteria
    private boolean isValidWord(String word) {
        // You can define your own criteria for a valid word here
        // For example, check for minimum length, only alphabetic characters, etc.
        return word.matches("[a-z]+") && word.length() >= 4;
    }
```

Is there a simpler way to access the EnglishWords.txt file or am I approaching this the wrong way? Or if its just a silly mistake.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no words are checked when its run"? Do you mean you are reading the words correctly from the file but `isValidWord(line)` is always returning false?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's saying isValidWord(line) is always false. I'm assuming this is because it isn't reading the .txt file properly.

Comment: You've misinterpreted the rules. In `checkValidWord()`, a valid word does NOT have to start with the center letter. The center letter simply must be SOMEWHERE in the word. So this code is wrong: `if (word.charAt(0) != puzzle.charAt(0)) { return false; }` You do need to get the center letter with `puzzle.charAt(0)` or `puzzle.substring(0, 1)`, but then you simply need to know if that letter is anywhere in `word`.  Use `String.indexOf()` to figure that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your problem is finding a valid word, i.e. implementing method:

```java
private boolean checkValidWord(String word, String puzzle)
```

As I understand the instructions, a valid word meets the following conditions:

- Must have at least four letters.
- Must contain the first letter in `puzzle`.
- Must also contain only letters in `puzzle`.

Also, according to your sample "dictionary" file, all words in that file are lowercase only. Hence I assume that [method] parameter `word` is a word from the "dictionary" file and therefore **must** be all lowercase.

```java
private boolean checkValidWord(String word, String puzzle) {
    boolean valid = false;
    if (word.length() > 3) {
        puzzle = puzzle.toLowercase();
        if (word.indexOf(puzzle.charAt(0)) >= 0) {
            valid = true;
            for (int i = word.length(); --i >= 0  &&  valid;) {
                valid = puzzle.indexOf(word.charAt(i)) >= 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

`puzzle` is converted to lowercase in preparation for comparing it with `word` which, as already stated, is assumed to be all lowercase only.

The above code first checks whether `word` is the required length.

Next `word` is checked to see if it contains the first letter of `puzzle`.

Finally, each letter in `word` is checked to see whether that letter also appears in `puzzle`. As soon as a letter in `word` is **not** in `puzzle`, the `for` loop terminates. The value of `valid` – after the `for` loop has terminated – is the value returned by the method `checkValidWord`.

Comment: managed to get it working tweaking a little with this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code a bit. See if this works with your word list:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WordList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new WordList().readWordsFromFile(args[0]));
    }

    public List<String> readWordsFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        List<String> words = null;
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Path.of(filename))) {
            words = lines.filter(WordList::isValidWord).map(String::toLowerCase).toList();

        }
        return words;
    }

    // Check if a word is valid based on your criteria
    private static boolean isValidWord(String word) {
        // You can define your own criteria for a valid word here
        // For example, check for minimum length, only alphabetic characters, etc.
        return word.matches("\\p{Alpha}{4,}");
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires a separate class right, and its only for sorting the words, right? How do i implement the object into my main class?

Comment: I'm just showing you alternative and more direct ways of using the functionality you already have. It's in its own class so it's runnable. You can put the methods where you need them